# Should I use Thread.Sleep() to check if a process is still running?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sleep

As title says, I'm currently making a WPF application and I need to detect if an application is running and do something when it's closed. The way I'd thought of doing so is by running a separate Thread and checking every two seconds if the process is still running, something like this:

```
while(Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length != 0) {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

//Do something
```

Would this be a good solution, is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already dealing with Processes, I would suggest just using it directly to determine if it has exited. You can use the [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.8) event handler for your code. So, for instance:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName))
{
  process.Exited += new EventHandler(DoSomething);
}

…

public void DoSomething(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  // do something
}
```

This will call `DoSomething` when the process with that name ends.

Comment: Dude, you're a lifesaver, now I don't have to be checking all the time, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Would this be a good solution?

No, because it would waste an entire thread for nearly nothing.

Better use a timer, in a WPF application preferrably a DispatcherTimer:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };

timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length > 0)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

timer.Start();
```

---

If there would be a lengthy operation to be performed off the UI thread, you could use an async `Tick` event handler that awaits a `Task` (which would run on a thread pool thread in the background):

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };

timer.Tick += async (s, e) =>
{
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length > 0)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // lengthy operation here which runs on a thread pool thread
        });

        // udate UI here
    }
};

timer.Start();
```

Comment: The different Thread is necessary because the user should be able to do stuff in the UI while this operation is running in the background, so shoukd I use a timer instead of Thread.Sleep even then?

Comment: DispatcherTimer doesn't block the UI. If there is a lengthy operation to perform, use an async Tick handler. See the edit.

Comment: I'll be trying @mm8 solution, it runs on a different Thread so I think it suits my needs more, if not I'll try yours, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ÓscarFunesTrigo Actually you don't seem to need another thread. Or please explain what exactly the different thread is supposed to do. If there really is a lengthy operation that should run off the UI thread, then async/await is the correct approach. We do not actively deal with threads anymore today. Let the framework handle these things.

Comment: Fwiw. Task.run is a different thread, if you need one. But you don't really need a timer at all if you use async. You could just loop using await task.delay.

Comment: @Andy Sure it is, but we don't explicitly deal with that fact.

Comment: This is the functionality I need: I'm making a Steam-like application. An user can click on 'Play' on one of his games, and I need to check for how long the user plays (that's the server problem), and so I need to check every second or 2 seconds if the game is still open (since that's another different application, not handled by me). When it detects it's closed, it tells the server to stop counting time and add it to the user's game. So right now I'm just looking for an efficient way to check if the process is still running, and if it isn't, tell the server

Comment: @ÓscarFunesTrigo Ok, but checking if the process runs or not is not a lengthy operation. You don't need to do anything asynchronously or in a background thread. Just use a DispatcherTimer with a Tick event handler. It is called repeatedly without blocking the UI.

Comment: The code in the `Tick` event handler does block though.

Comment: @mm8 For the duration of GetProcessesByName. How long is that?

Comment: But my thought is, if I'm going to be checking that small operation every 2 seconds or so, won't that at some point be noticed by the user? I mean, it blocks the UI, so it'll probably be noticed at some point, won't it?

Comment: @ÓscarFunesTrigo It'll take a few milliseconds, and go without notice. You could even do the check multiple times per second. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `System.Timers.Timer` that performs the check every x seconds:

```
public sealed partial class Window1 : Window, IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds);

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("processName...").Length == 0)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Dispose();
            //do something...
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Unlike the `Tick` event of a `DispatcherTimer`, the `Elapsed` event of a `Timer` is always queued for execution on a thread pool thread.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.8):

> If a `System.Timers.Timer` is used in a WPF application, it is worth noting that the `System.Timers.Timer` runs on a different thread than the user interface (UI) thread...Reasons for using a `DispatcherTimer` as opposed to a `System.Timers.Timer` are that the `DispatcherTimer` runs on the same thread as the `Dispatcher` and a `DispatcherPriority` can be set on the `DispatcherTimer`.

Comment: I think I'll give this a try, I think it's more what I'm looking for, since it runs on a different Thread. Does the timer start as soon as it's assigned a value? I don't see a _timer.Start() or anything like that

Comment: @ÓscarFunesTrigo: No, sorry, you need to start it by calling `Start()` as per my edit.

Comment: Aah, I see. Can't try it til I get home, but thanks a lot! I'll comment the results